# index fragmentation in posgresql

Tags: postgresql

I can't figure out what exactly represent fragmentation for a postgres index. in the source code of pgstattuple I found this comment but it's not particularly clear for me.

/*
* If the next leaf is on an earlier block, it means a
* fragmentation.
*/

Comment: [REINDEX](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-reindex.html) mentions the reasons why it is needed to be done on databases.

Comment: I am not sure about that either. This is clearly underdocumented.

Answer (score 0):

Btree leaf pages form a logical chain (a doubly linked list) and if you follow that chain in the forward direction you encounter the key values in sorted order.  They also have a "physical" order, their block number within the file.  That extension considers it fragmentation if the next page following the linked list is to a "physically" earlier page in the file.

You could quibble with this for any number of reasons, but this is the definition that that extension adopted.  For example if the logically next page by the linked list is 100 pages forward, that is just as much fragmented as if it is one page backwards.  But if it does skip forward a bunch then someone *else* must be pointing backwards to pick them up (unless they are unused) so would get counted when that "someone else" is encountered.  Also, the "physical" order of pages in the file is really just the "logical" order of another layer of abstraction (the file system) and different file systems handle it differently.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's clearer now